# Saving image from BITMAPINFO

Tags: c++, bitmap

I have been trying to save an image that has been given as a BITMAPINFO* and a pointer to data.
I am currently trying to use the method Bitmap::FromBITMAPINFO as follows:

```
#include <gdiplusheaders.h>
#include "stdafx.h"

[...]
BITMAPINFO* bitMapInfo = (BITMAPINFO*) getPtrBitmapInfo();
void* bitMapData = (void*) getPtrBitmapBits();
Bitmap *image;
image = Bitmap::FromBITMAPINFO(bitMapInfo, bitMapData);
```

But VS 2019 gives me an error :
C++ static Bitmap *Bitmap::FromBITMAPINFO( BITMAPINFO) too many argument in function call

Any idea where this is coming from ?
Thanks !

Comment: The placement of `#include "stdafx.h"` is a bug. `#include "stdafx.h"` must be the first include. The compiler ignores all lines above the include of the precompiled header file.

Comment: @drescherjm Okay thanks so that is a good start, now it tells me that Bitmap is undefined. I should find the right include I guess.

Comment: Although shouldn't it be included in gdiplusheaders.h ?

Comment: ***tells me that Bitmap is undefined*** Is this a compile error or a linker error? The documentation says you need to link to `Gdiplus.lib` here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusheaders/nf-gdiplusheaders-bitmap-bitmap(hicon)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusheaders/nf-gdiplusheaders-bitmap-bitmap(hicon))

Comment: So it was a compilation error, I had to call Gdiplus::Bitmap and Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromBITMAPINFO. Now it compiles!

Comment: You may want to answer your own question showing the changes to the code and a brief description of the changes you made.

Comment: [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusheaders/nf-gdiplusheaders-bitmap-frombitmapinfo) instructs you to include `Gdiplus.h` for this.

Answer (score -1):

So I finaly made it work and saved the image:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <gdiplusheaders.h>

[...]
BITMAPINFO* bitMapInfo = (BITMAPINFO*) getPtrBitmapInfo();
void* bitMapData = (void*) getPtrBitmapBits();
Gdiplus::Bitmap *image;
image = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromBITMAPINFO(bitMapInfo, bitMapData);
CLSID bmpClsid;
CLSIDFromString(L"{557cf400-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}", &bmpClsid);
image->Save(L"File.bmp", &bmpClsid, NULL);

//bmp: {557cf400-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}
//jpg: {557cf401-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}
//gif: {557cf402-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}
//tif: {557cf405-1a04-11d3-9a73-0000f81ef32e}
```